# Template part including not working

Tags: templates

I have since tried a blank and new php file and accessing it the same way - that worked. So I am now unclear why the existing file does not load at all. There are no errors. Here is the code start of the template part I am getting:

```
<?php
   require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/themename/includes/file1.php';
   require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/themename/includes/file2.php';
   require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/themename/includes/file3.php';
     
   if(isset($_GET["ict"])){
       $id_category[] = "'{$_GET["ict"]}'";
       $variable1= new file3();
```

I am trying to include a partial template and have read up on how to do so.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php get_template_part('/partials/category.php');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The file I have included the above code in is in the theme main. The partial is in a folder in the theme main called partials. When I use `/partials/category.php` I get a blank with no PHP error in the area of the page where the information should be.

If I dont use the `/` on front of partials I get an error.

I have also tried removing the `/` on the front and at the same time removing the `.php` at the end. Same result where there is no error and no output

What am I missing about getting the template part to display>?

Here is the blank space where this should display
[image]

Comment: What is the error you get? Why do you include the `.php` extension?

Comment: no error. Just tried it a number of ways. Its blank. I have since tried a blank and new php file and accessing it the same way - that worked. So I am now unclear why the existing file does not

Comment: what do you mean by _tried a blank_? And when you said "I get a blank with no php error in the area of the page" can you be more specific? I can think of multiple things this could mean. e.g the page stops loading when it reaches that line, or the page runs as if the line isn't present, etc. Have you checked your PHP error log? Are you sure `partials/category.php` actually has output?

Comment: Thanks yes I am 100% it has output as it is used elsewhere successfully. I literally mean a blank in the space where I would expect to see the content. Just nothing there.

Comment: if it's used elsewhere successfully then can't you copy paste that to this location? What does the inside of that file look like? I do not understand what you mean by a blank in the space, it does not make sense as a phrase, the grammar makes no sense, can you describe using different words?

Comment: and have you checked your PHP error log?

Comment: I added a picture since I am not successfully describing blank. It is used elsewhere in a different way. I am not sure how you mean what does the inside of the file look like? its starts with `require once` files

Comment: I am not sure how to check the error log?

Comment: I noticed you updated your question with a screenshot, but it isn't clear if that is the end of the output, does the output stop at the `get_template_part` call? What is inside `/partials/category.php`?

Comment: Your host can help you check the PHP error log

Comment: Also you should not start with `/` and you should not end with `.php`

Comment: re removing / and .php ok thank you done. I also added code above as an example

Comment: Complete side note, you should be filtering the `$_GET` variable using `filter_input` or `filter_var`, e.g. `$id_category[] = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'ict', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );`.

Comment: @phatskat thank you. I have been stuck withsomeone else's code and am slowly fixing it up that is good advice

Comment: No problem @user15081222 - maybe take a look at setting up `phpcs` and the WordPress Coding Standards. Tom McFarlin has a writeup on setting it up here with VsCode, most editors also have some way of doing linting and diagnostics: https://github.com/tommcfarlin/phpcs-wpcs-vscode

Comment: I will do that. This code is all over the place and I dont know all that much. I am still trying to figure out though why this wont display as a template part

Comment: @user15081222 now that you've included the top of that files contents, there's a really obvious problem, the files you are trying to include don't exist! `WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/themename/includes/file1.php'` translates to soemthing like this: `wp-content/plugins/themename/includes/file1.php`, and themes don't go in the plugin directory. You shouldn't be directly including theme files from other themes like that, and even if you did you shouldn't be using the plugin directory. Your PHP error log should be filled with error messages reporting that you tried to require a file that doesn't exist

Comment: Also, `"'{$_GET["ict"]}'"` should just be `$_GET["ict"]`, you don't need the quotes, and if the files you are including are in the parent theme and hold classes then you should not need to require theme, the parent theme should be loading them. *TLDR: `get_template_part` did work! It was the `category.php` file that was broken all along*. you can prove this by putting `echo "hello world";` at the very top of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get_template_part` call is successful, it's the file it loads that is broken

```php
<?php get_template_part( 'partials/category' ); ?>
```

If you swap the contents of that file for this:

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Then it will work as expected.

The cause of your problem is this:

```php
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/themename/includes/file1.php';
```

- you should not be including files from other themes directly
- themes don't go in the plugins/`WP_PLUGIN_DIR` folder
- PHP can't find the file so it exits with a fatal error

You should see confirmation of this in your PHP error log

Comment: got it thank you for letting me know. Dealing with others code, when it isnt proper is rough